# Fetch new data when date picker changes

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I use `MudBlazor` and I have the following code in a Blazor Webassembly page (minimal example):

```
<MudDatePicker @bind-Date="@_chosenDate" />

@* Display data based on date above, here it is just an integer *@

@code {
    private DateTime? _chosenDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    private int data = 0;

    private async Task FetchData()
    {
        await FetchDataFromApi(_chosenDate);
    }
}
```

Note that the default chosen date is set to today's date. Apparently, the `MudDatePicker` can only bind to a nullable `DateTime`, so that's why I set it to `DateTime?`.

**Question:**
How do I fetch data from the API based on the new chosen value when the date is changed? I'm not sure what the proper way to do it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to `DateChanged` event and handle it:

```
<MudDatePicker Date="@_chosenDate" DateChanged="OnDateChange" /> // Date instead of @bind-Date

@code {
    private DateTime? _chosenDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    private int data = 0;

    private async Task FetchData()
    {
        await FetchDataFromApi(_chosenDate);
    }

    async void OnDateChange(DateTime? newDate)
    {
        _chosenDate = newDate;

        await FetchData();
    }   
}
```

Comment: So, I am not supposed to use `bind-Date` (or for another component `bind-Value`) for this?

Comment: In your case no need to use two-way binding as you set the value when `DateChanged` event is fired.